# Replicate excel's product function in Tableau

Tags: function, excel-formula, tableau-api, calculation, quantitative-finance

I am trying to find the product of a series of financial returns in Tableau. In Excel, you can use **Product(1+Value)-1** , but the Product function does not exist in Tableau.

Other people who have ran into the same issue have used this formula to solve their issue:
**EXP(SUM(LN(1+[Field Name])))-1**

My data has negative and positive values, however, so I tried using **EXP(SUM(LN(ABS(1+[Field Name]-1))))**. This works almost perfectly for my case except that a few of the product values should be negative. I'm really not sure how I can resolve this issue. I need the absolute value to use the workaround formula but I also need the product value to be correct in Tableau. I would appreciate any help!

For those unfamiliar with Product, the function is calculating **((1+Value) * (1+Value) * (1+Value))-1**. I essentially want to replicate this formula/procedure in Tableau to avoid any miscalculations.

| DATE | My Data | Excel Product | Tableau Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/30/23 | 1.23 | -2.89923 | 2.899 |
|  | -0.97 |  |  |
|  | 2.43 |  |  |
| 10/31/23 | -1.33 | 26.99634 | 26.996 |
|  | -3.4 |  |  |
|  | 5.97 |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to move the ABS function around until it's doing what you want.